# Files automatically added

Tags: plugin-development, uploads, filesystem, hacks, hacked

Today I was warned by iTheme Security that were added 2 files:

```
wp -content / uploads / GeoIP.dat
wp / content / uploads / GeoIPv6.dat
```

Where did these come from and what is their purpose?

Answer (score 2):

Those are Geo IP databases which tie IP addresses to countries. They probably came from some e-commerce plugin, or a cookie-law plugin, or some other country-specific tool.

Comment: I have woocommerce . Can came from it ?

Comment: Yes it can: https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/66c61eebc83348af4c42856539cd918a8e181fa9/includes/class-wc-geolocation.php#L19